# Cordova/Phonegap Plugins for Blackberry

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, blackberry

In my Phonegap application I would like to implement login for Twitter and Facebook, and sharing for BlackBerry. Are there any plugins available for that? Preferably, a single plugin would handle iOS, Android and BlackBerry.

Comment: Please answer as soon as possible, It is urgent functionality.

Comment: why do you need a phonegap plugin ? You can do it entirely in JS...

Comment: Are you talking about Blackberry OS 7 or Blackberry 10?

Answer (score 3):

If I were you, I would have ported my PhoneGap app to WebWorks and let the invocation framework ( in case of BB10 ) do it for me.

Comment: I asked for all BB versions

Answer (score 1):

As you have probably seen, the availability of plugins on the Blackberry platform is very sparse and to my knowledge a "plugin" for Blackberry that delivers the functionality you desire does not yet exist. You may instead like to contribute to the community by adding Blackberry functionality to these plugins :

[PhoneGap Facebook Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin)

[PhoneGap Twitter Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Twitter)